# How do I solve the triangle?

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a given triangle, such that $AD=3$, $DE=5$, $EC=24$ and $∠ABE=90^\circ$, $∠DBC=90^\circ$, where $D$ and $E$ are points on $AC$ (and$ D$ is between $A$ and $E$). Then, find the length of $AB$. I tried applying Stewart's theorem but the calculations are getting nasty for the two triangles. If I apply Sine law thrice, I am running in circles(getting the same thing again and again). Is there any other method to solve?

Comment: The points $B$ such that $\angle ABE=\pi/2$ form a circle with diameter $AE$; the points $B$ such that $\angle DBC = \pi/2$ form a circle with diameter $DB$. Try finding $B$ as the point of intersection between those two circles, using either coordinates or geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $M$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$ and let $DM = x, BM = y.$

by equating the power of $M,$ we get $$(3+x)(5-x) = y^2 = x(29-x)$$ gives $x = 5/9$ 
and $y^2 =  (3+\dfrac{5}{9})(5-\dfrac{5}{9})$ but 
$AB^2 = y^2 + (3+\dfrac{5}{9})^2 =\dfrac{32}{9}(\dfrac{40}{9} + \dfrac{32}{9})=\dfrac{16^2}{3^2} $ so $AB = 16/3.$

Answer (score 1):

The point be should be in the intersection of those two orange circles:

[image]

Their equations can be easily derived:

$(x-(\frac{3+5}{2}))^2+y^2=(\frac{3+5}{2})^2 ... (1)$

$(x-(3+\frac{(5+24)}{2}))^2+y^2=(\frac{24+5}{2}) ... (2)$

Now you have to solve for $(1)=(2)$ and tell us the result

P.S: 
I built the equations upon the assumption of a system of coordinates where $A$ is the origin and $A,D,E,C$ are in its X-Axis